# How to completely close/release a WebView after it has loaded a youtube link?

Tags: uwp

We are developing an UWP app.
We use a WebView control which navigates to an youtube link, the issue is the video/sound from youtube doesn't stop after closing the WebView.

Is there any way to release a webview?

Comment: How you close the WebView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop sound you need to remove all references to your WebView and let GC to collect it. Removing it from layout and calling GC manually should do the trick immediately.

Comment: Well in that case, you sure that `WebView.Navigate(new Uri("about:blank"));` will not work for you? I just checked it and it navigates to blank page just fine.

Comment: Thanks Andrey! 
Yes, we decide to navigate to blank page, it works fine to us!